# Externally loaded javascript's function is undefined

Tags: javascript

I use this code for loading the script:

```
if(!checkAlreadyLoaded || !Engine.Loader.isLoaded(file))
    {

        var newScript = document.createElement("script");
        newScript.onload = function()
        {
            if(onLoad != undefined && onLoad != null)
                onLoad();
        };
        newScript.type = "text/javascript"
        newScript.src = file;


        if(newScript != undefined)
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newScript);
        else
            alert("Failed to load!");
    }
```

and it loads scripts perfectly but when I try to access any scripts the script is undefined. But If I add them in the head of the html page where I am adding the loader it works perfectly fine.

```
<head>

    <script src="scripts/Engine/Loader.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

</head>
```

Here is the code where the problem is occurring:

```
    loadScript(file)
    {
        if(!checkAlreadyLoaded || !Engine.Loader.isLoaded(file))
        {

        var newScript = document.createElement("script");
        newScript.onload = function()
        {
            if(onLoad != undefined && onLoad != null)
                onLoad();
        };
        newScript.type = "text/javascript"
        newScript.src = file;


        if(newScript != undefined)
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newScript);
        else
            alert("Failed to load!");
       }
    }     

    loadEngine: function()
    {       
    var engineScripts =
    [
        "scripts/Engine/GameLoop.js",
        "scripts/Engine/Utilities.js",
        "scripts/Engine/Client.js",
        "scripts/Engine/Renderer.js",
        "scripts/Engine/Input.js",
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < engineScripts.length; i++)
        Engine.Loader.loadScript(engineScripts[i]);
    GameLoop gameLoop = new GameLoop(new Client("ws:/192.168.105:8080"), new Renderer());
    gameLoop.initialise();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: try appending it in the body?

Comment: The way you add the scripts is asynchronous. You'll have to wait for the script to load before you can use it, just like you do with the `newScript.onload` function.

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately the scripts are still undefined :(

Comment: You'll have to show the code that doesn't work. It's impossible to tell what could be wrong if you don't show the code. See [mcve].

Comment: @JJJ were right! when I put the accessed the scripts in the onload listener it worked! Could you post it as an answer?